# TWS - what is the better way to schedule job to run twice a day...?

Tags: tivoli, workload-scheduler, tivoli-work-scheduler

I need to schedule job to run twice a day everyday i.e. first run at 1 AM and second run at 11 PM. As you can see there is no way I can use option "repeat range".

So my question is what is the better way to do it:
1. set two run cycles (DAILY and DAILY2), check the "use as time dependency" and set the earliest start for each
2. create two identical jobs (with different names) and set the time restriction on the job level (under one run cycle DAILY)

It seems like there is no difference, but in TWS you never know so what do you recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use 2 different runcycles with different start times defined at runcycle level.

The use of "use as time dependency" is optional in this scenario, this is up to you if you want to not start before 1 AM / 11 PM or if this is just to create 2 instances with 2 different schedTime and resolve the dependencies according to these schedTimes.